# Scroll the page almost to the end in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I need scrool page in Selenium almost to the end of page (150 px until bottom). But my code doesn't work. It's scroll to bottom. How it's fix?

```
IWebElement element = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight-150)");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 150)");
```

A few notes:

- You are executing a command to scroll, which does not return an `IWebElement`, so there is no need to have the `IWebElement element =` part.
- You don't need the `javascript:` part either
- Since you want to scroll to an absolute position, [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo) is a better fit

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to the necessary location using javascript's scrollTo method.

```
public void scrollToElement(By by) {
  Locatable element = (Locatable) selenium.findElement(by);
  Point p= element.getCoordinates().getLocationOnScreen();
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) selenium;  
  js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + p.getX() + "," + (p.getY()) + ");");
}
```

Comment: good answer, because i found it useful for my scenario, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me :)

```
  public IWebElement ScrollTo(IWebElement element)
            {
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
                return element;
            }
```